# How to do 'signTransaction' after authenticated by 'signPersonalMessage' by WalletConnect of '@walletconnect/react-native-dapp'?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ethereum, web3js, wallet-connect

I am developing a react native mobile app where user can connect their existing wallet(rainbow, metamask and many more) to app.

I have already done the authentication part, like user can successfully connect their app wallet to app by this code.

```
import { useWalletConnect } from '@walletconnect/react-native-dapp';

const connector = useWalletConnect();

await connector.connect();

const message = `App name is XYZ - ${new Date().toUTCString()}`;
  const hexMsg = convertUtf8ToHex(message);
  const address = connector.accounts[0];
  await setItemToStorage('address', address);
  const msgParams = [hexMsg, address];
  connector.signPersonalMessage(msgParams).then(async result => {
    let data = {
      message,
      signature: result,
    };
```

Now every thing is working as expected.
And then I have to transfer my wallet amount to other address, and to achieve this I know I have to get permission from wallet app,

To achieve this I am trying to do like

```
let txObj = {
  gas: Web3js.utils.toHex(100000),
  to: receiver_address!,
  data: data,
  from: userWallet,
};
console.log('Start transaction...');

const singTrasaction = await connector.signTransaction(txObj);
```

The `connector.signTransaction(txObj)` open the wallet app but not prompted me to confirm.

I am just confused and nothing get help me.

Please help me anyone I am getting stuck on this since a week.

Comment: can u write `const singTrasaction = await connector.signTransaction(txObj)` inside `try/catch`

Comment: yes I did, but nothing get print

Comment: One more thing if I remove data parameter from object then the confirmation prompted but network is not same. it shows for some other network balance

Comment: @Yilmaz please check if you can help me

Comment: I am creating data object like that

Comment: const Web3js = new Web3(
          new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
            'https://matic-mumbai.chainstacklabs.com/',
          ),
        );      
        let toAddress = '0x2BFe0b62b279fBe577388dE92C5a796cc7647197';
        let decimals = BigNumber(18);
        let amount1 = new BigNumber(5);
        let value = amount1.times(new BigNumber(10).pow(decimals));

        let contract = new Web3js.eth.Contract(App_ABI, POZ_TOKEN!);
        let dataa = contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, value).encodeABI();

Comment: do you have a github repo

Comment: @Yilmaz, Thanks for your help, However I have implemented flow in my app and it working as expected

Comment: @PankajSonava what was the solution?

Comment: i am stuck with the same, it does not prompt to sign @PankajSonava

Comment: @0xgareth, I have used approve method of my contractor instead of transfer method.